# No 3 dots option on whats app on my Samsung Galaxy Grade

Tags: 4.2-jelly-bean

i don't have that 3 dots( which usually is in the top rhs) so I can't change my profile picture on my what's app

Answer (score 4):

If your device have hardware buttons like menu,home,back buttons, you can get those options by **clicking Menu button**. Those 3 dots denotes menu options for an App. Actually its useful for devices with capacitive(software) buttons. Currently I'm not sure about your device, and I can't find any device named Galaxy Grade. I you meant Galaxy Grand it have hardware buttons and you can use Menu button as mentioned earlier.